# Restricted area in S3 bucket with cognito authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I'm starting with AWS. I want to create a flat-file website hosted in S3 with a restricted area protected by a password. I'm doing user authentication with Amazon Cognito.

For the restriction of unlogged users there is a problem, I can't just serve flat files and check for the JWT token with javascript, because the user can easily disable javascript or mess with it and still read the file.

How to protect/restrict access in this case? Does Amazon S3 provide any restriction or redirection of access for unlogged cognito users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using AWS Cognito Federated identities, you can define two distinguish IAM roles to assume for authenticated users and unauthenticated users.

In each of these role policies, you can define which part of S3 is allowed to access and the actions you can perform.

Note: If you are currently using Cognito Userpools, you can connect it with Cognito Federated Identities to implement this feature.